# How to create Polygons of a specific size?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, postgis, polygon, polygon-creation

I'm trying to create polygons of **specific size in square meters** that represent the areas surrounded by roads. The roads are stored in PostGIS as points / lines. If required, I can convert the data to other formats for processing in other softwares like ArcGIS etc.

Because of the randomness of the roads, the polygons could differ in size but their size should not be less than the specified size.

See the below picture. For illustration, I have set different colors to the possible polygons of equal size fulfilling minimum size constraint.

Can somebody please mention how can I achieve this? As I am beginner so sample query or code would greatly help. I have basic know how of PostGIS, QGIS and ArcGIS but I am willing to use any other software if it solves my problem.

[image]

If the street network looks like below, polygons like given in red needs to be created (only as an example, in fact all the intersections between streets **fulfilling the minimum area constraint** should produce polygons like these).

Let suppose we want to create polygons of minimum 2 square kilometer area and let suppose that the area made up of 3 white patches shown in blue is of 2 square kilometer then the code should create a polygon consisting these 3 white patches. You can see that polygon 3 is larger than the polygon 1 but fulfilling the minimum size constraint, similarly polygon 2 has four white patches to fulfill the minimum size constraint.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you want to create polygons of the areas *enclosed* by roads...? I.e. parcels? Is that area you are talking about actually the parcel size?

Comment: I want to create polygons of the specific size of the areas enclosed by roads. For example, if the required polygons size is 2km then the code should be able to find the roads which collectively make about 2km polygon.

Comment: In short, Yes! I want to create polygons of the areas enclosed by roads!

Comment: So...would it be okay to actually create those polygons using the *roads as bounds*? No size calacularions involved?

Comment: I think creating polygons using the roads as bounds without calculations may create some polygons of size less than the required minimum size.

Comment: Okay, see if my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/331559) does what you need: it will polygonize all areas enclosed by roads. I don't get what you intend exactly, but doing a similar thing by size is problematic. You may want to rather union some of the polygonized parcels to match your requirement. You may need to specify your question further.

Comment: Here is question in which the op has asked for creating polygons out of ONLY the white areas enclosed by roads, but one can see that some white areas are small and some are large. In our case, let suppose our minimum polygon size requirement was 2km and there were TWO WHITE spaces making up 2km areas then we would make a polygon consisting of those two white spaces enclosed by the roads. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52014/creating-polygons-of-area-surrounded-by-roads-lines-using-postgis

Comment: @ThingumaBob updated question and added a picture for clarification.

Comment: You need a common attribute to collect and union the required roads (or areas), if you want *specific* areas as result. Or do you not care for which areas are unioned across your data, as long as they are above a certain size?

Comment: Yes, I don't care for which areas are unioned across my data as I want to make polygons out of all data, not a specific region.

Comment: @ThingumaBob I updated question for more clarity.

Comment: Is it important to maximize the coverage of the output layer?

Comment: @OGmaps you can think of it like so.

Comment: It's polygon grouping task, see this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/grouping-village-points-based-on-distance-and-population-size-using-arcgis-deskt/123297#123297

Comment: @FelixIP It would be a lot helpful if you please post Answer containing a sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Tested approach mentioned.Results:

[image]

[image]

Script posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcgis-for-desktop) should do the job.